# How to concatenate values as string in PromQL?

Tags: grafana, promql

I have some devices that report their firmware version as three separate numbers in Prometheus.

```
firmwareMajorVersion{instance="10.49.54.169", job="snmp_qsys_core"} 9
firmwareMinorVersion{instance="10.49.54.169", job="snmp_qsys_core"} 6
firmwareBuildVersion{instance="10.49.54.169", job="snmp_qsys_core"} 0
```

How can I get this value as a single string `9.6.0` ?  My goal is to track it in Grafana state timeline.

Comment: Prometheus is not good in relations between labels and values, because it's against their design principals. As a workaround you can convert your versions to something like `9006000` (with simple arithmetic on metrics), but I'm not sure what you are planning to show on state timeline and if this approach might help you in your desire.